# Fourier transform giving powers or polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Is it possible to have a function $f$ so that its Fourier transform looks like (or is) $x^n$?

I would have liked to use Fourier inversion formula, but I feel that there is a convergence issue at $0$ with the Fourier transform. Can we massage it a bit so that it is still close enough?

Comment: Up to constant factors depending on your choice of convention, the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta distribution is the constant function $1$. Its $n^{th}$ distributional derivative $\delta^{(n)}$ has Fourier transform equal to the polynomial $x^n$. We have to venture out into the realm of tempered distributions because as you hopefully know from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is in $C_0$ (i.e the FT of an absolutely integrable function is continuous and vanishes at $\infty$… something which a polynomial doesn’t do).